# Can you fake the Host attribute of a C# URI?

Tags: .net

I was wondering if you can fake the Uri.Host value of a string. For example, given the following code:

```
new Uri(url.ToLower()).Host == "example.com"
```

Is there anyway to have this boolean comparison be true, but at the same time the URL go to a different server than example.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no intentional or known way, and probably (hopefully) no way at all. If there were, it would be a very serious bug in the .NET framework.

However, note that this only guarantees that the host is actually example.com; it doesn't guarantee that traffic for this URI destined for example.com will actually make it there without interception.